# Combining Using Two Columns

Tags: r, dplyr

A very basic question about merging interchangable columns.

Say I have a table

```
  subject stim1 stim2 Chosen Tchosen
     <dbl> <int> <int>  <int>   <int>
 1       1     1     2      1       4
 2       1     1     2      2      15
 3       1     1     3      1       2
 4       1     1     3      3      13
 5       1     2     1      1       2
 6       1     2     1      2      13
 7       1     2     3      2       3
```

where stim1 and stim 2 are interchangable (Stim1=1,Stim2=2 is equivalent to Stim1=2, Stim2=1)

What is the simplest way to merge the data so that Tchosen is added from the two equivalent columns (though Chosen and by subject should be maintained distinctly)

Desired output

```
   subject stim1 stim2 Chosen Tchosen
     <dbl> <int> <int>  <int>   <int>
 1       1     1     2      1       6
 2       1     1     2      2      28
 3       1     1     3      1       4
 4       1     1     3      3      28
 5       1     2     3      2       3
 6       1     2     3      3      12...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` approach.. could not reproduce your desired output, since it contains values that are not in your sample data?

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("  subject stim1 stim2 Chosen Tchosen
       1     1     2      1       4
       1     1     2      2      15
       1     1     3      1       2
       1     1     3      3      13
       1     2     1      1       2
       1     2     1      2      13
       1     2     3      2       3")

# Switch values of stim2 and stim1 if stim2 < stim1
DT[stim2 < stim1, `:=`(stim1 = stim2, stim2 = stim1)]
# Now summarise and sum
DT[, .(Tchosen = sum(Tchosen, na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(subject,stim1, stim2, Chosen)]
#    subject stim1 stim2 Chosen Tchosen
# 1:       1     1     2      1       6
# 2:       1     1     2      2      28
# 3:       1     1     3      1       2
# 4:       1     1     3      3      13
# 5:       1     2     3      2       3
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. When running it I get a object 'stim2' not found error even though it is definitely a column. Any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: Is your data in data.table format? if not, use `setDT(mydata)` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `merge` + `rowSums`

```
transform(
  merge(df,
    df,
    by.x = c("subject", "stim1", "stim2", "Chosen"),
    by.y = c("subject", "stim2", "stim1", "Chosen"),
    all.x = TRUE
  ),
  Tchosen = rowSums(cbind(Tchosen.x, Tchosen.y), na.rm = TRUE)
)
```

which gives

```
  subject stim1 stim2 Chosen Tchosen.x Tchosen.y Tchosen
1       1     1     2      1         4         2       6
2       1     1     2      2        15        13      28
3       1     1     3      1         2        NA       2
4       1     1     3      3        13        NA      13
5       1     2     1      1         2         4       6
6       1     2     1      2        13        15      28
7       1     2     3      2         3        NA       3
```

where `NA` exists probably due to the incomplete data in your post.

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), stim1 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), stim2 = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L
), Chosen = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Tchosen = c(4L, 15L,
2L, 13L, 2L, 13L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pmin`/`pmax` to sort `stim1` and `stim2` columns and calculate `sum` for each group.

```
aggregate(Tchosen~., transform(df, stim1 = pmin(stim1, stim2), 
                                   stim2 = pmax(stim1, stim2)), sum)

#  subject stim1 stim2 Chosen Tchosen
#1       1     1     2      1       6
#2       1     1     3      1       2
#3       1     1     2      2      28
#4       1     2     3      2       3
#5       1     1     3      3      13
```